# How to query min and max when a column consists of different several strings

Tags: sql-server

I am still learning SQL query. I have a table looks like this:

The Financial_Year_Month_Code consists of the "year" and P01 stands for Period 1. The Calendar Key is just the year month day.

```
|---------------------------|--------------|--------------------        
| Financial_Year_Month_Code | Calendar_Key | Column 3...  
|---------------------------|--------------|--------------------  
| 1988 P01                  | 19870901     |
| ......
| 2013 P01                  | 20110901     |                 
| 2013 P01                  | 20110902     |            
| 2013 P01                  | 20110903     |           
| 2013 P01                  | .....        |            
| 2013 P02                  | 20111002     |           
| 2013 P02                  | 20111003     |            
| 2013 P02                  | 20111004     |           
| MORE...
```

The result I want to query should look like this:

```
|----------------------|------------------|--------------------|-----------------|        
| Financial_Code_Start | Calendar_Key_Min | Financial_Code_End |Calendar_key_max |  
|----------------------|------------------|--------------------|-----------------|  
| 2013 P02             | 20110901         | 2014 P01           | 20120930        |                
| 2013 P03             | 20111002         | 2014 P02           | 20121029        |
| ....
```

The original table has a huge list of Financial Year Code from 1988 to 2014. The management would like me to produce a table above to list the financial year code between 2012 and 2014 so they can see the start date and the end date of a rolling 12 month period. Too bad, our developers are all on holiday at the moment so I need help on this one. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You can group a query by Financial_Year_Month_Code and then calculate aggregates (like MIN and MAX) for each group.

```
SELECT Financial_Year_Month_Code, MIN(Calendar_Key), MAX(Calendar_Key) 
FROM YOUR_TABLE 
GROUP BY Financial_Year_Month_Code
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, this is my first post so I wasn't thorough enough. The financial year month code span from 1988 to 2014. How do I query a list of min and max Calendar_Key for Financial_Year_Month_Code say from 2012 to 2013 please?

Comment: I'm sorry, i am not sure if I understand correctly. So you dont want the aggregates for month code (2013 P01, 2013 P02, ...) but per year (2013, 2012, ..) ? Can you maybe provide an example of how the result should look like?